Can Blazor WebAssembly app call service on non-web app?
I've been tasked with writing a Blazor WebAssembly application that will need to communicate with another app that is not a web app.  This "server" would likely be a standalone .NET 8 app with network access that would execute some C++ modules for premium performance.  The Blazor app would request a JSON-serialized object from the standalone app.  I'm trying to determine what communication protocol/method I should use.  Is there some way this standalone app can somehow host a web server that can expose web APIs, and be more like the examples I've been finding?  ROS2 is also something we were thinking about for communication between apps.  Thanks...

Blazor WebAssembly runs in the browser so you are very limited to what other protocols you can use. My personal approach would be to go for the standard with http protocol and a web api as backend. The "server" app could get some endpoints the wasm app can call.
